# How can I view the gui for a virtual machine on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I set my main machine to run Ubuntu Server because my old Optiplex finally bit the dust (RIP). I'm trying to set up a virtual machine using Ubuntu Server as a host and just allocate resources as needed to a Windows 10 VM. To be specific, I want to access that VM directly at the machine, not remotely. How do I do that? Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this a headless server? If not, what have you tried, what failed and why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious approach would be to use an RDP client on Ubuntu to connect to the VM. Remmina is the ubuntu default RDP client.  Simply connect to the IP of the windows VM.

If you are asking whether you can access the console of the VM from Ububtu. To do that you'll need to install `virt-manager` and use the gui it provides